# GoDaddy's 301 redirect/forwarding has some weird random middleman URL, kills link juice?

Tags: seo, domains, 301-redirect, godaddy

I'm trying to use GoDaddy's 301 redirect, which is named as domain forwarding. I set up forwarding `DomainA.example` to `DomainB.example` as 301 "type".

I noticed `DomainA.example` is still indexed in Google after ~6 months, and it has a title in SERP of `DomainB.example`. When I click it on Google or visit in the browser, it redirects to `DomainB.example`, so everything is fine from UX perspective.

I've inspected `DomainA.example` with the http://www.webconfs.com/redirect-check.php tool and found out, that `http://DomainA.example/` actually redirects to `http://DomainA.example/MmSWZ/`. And then this URL supposedly redirects to `DomainB.example`. What is that?

If I check again a few minutes later on the same tool, I see `http://DomainA.example/` redirects to `http://DomainA.example/MpppZ/`, so it's a unique random middle-man URL every single time it seems!

I'm sure it's bad for SEO. How do I fix it?

Comment: I can confirm the problem with my domains that redirect using Godaddy's forwarding service.   Godaddy is 302 redirecting to a random directory, then redirecting back to the home page, then finally 301 redirecting to the other domain.   WTF, Godaddy?

Comment: Evidentially this problem has been happening for months or years and hundreds of domains have reported it: [My domain name not resolving correctly, 6 random characters are being added to the path](https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/My-domain-name-not-resolving-correctly-6-random-characters-are/td-p/60782) and [Domain forwarding working intermittently: http:// to http://www.](https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/Domain-forwarding-working-intermittently-http-to-http-www/td-p/60878)

Comment: I will stop using godaddy's services forever if it's not possible to fix this junk nonsense. Advising you to do the same, vote with your dollars

Answer (score 1):

In order to do a 301 redirect, there needs to be a server at the specified location to reply to the browser's request for content with a location like:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://domainb.example
```

This is necessary because the server has to reply to the browser over HTTP with a response. This kind of redirect cannot be done with DNS because that is not the purpose of DNS.

You might consider setting a `CNAME` record for `DomainA.example` with `DomainB.example` as the value. Your DNS zone might look something like:

```
NAME                    TYPE   VALUE
--------------------------------------------------
www.domaina.example.    CNAME  www.domainb.example.
www.domainb.example.    A      192.0.2.23
```

You would also have to ensure that any `MX` records (tells mail servers where to send email for a domain) for `DomainA.example` are updated to point to the host at `DomainB.example` so email can be routed accordingly (if necessary).

Comment: Godaddy runs servers that do nothing but redirect domains.   They offer these redirects as a free service that you can choose after registering the domain.   This answer doesn't really address why Godaddy's servers aren't working properly, but the information in this answer could be useful for setting up redirects somewhere that does work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem occur on several different domains controled by GoDaddy. I attempted several times to contact GoDaddy support to resolve the issue with no luck. Ultimately I decided to solve the problem myself because GoDaddy seems clueless to their problem.

**Here is my solution:** Add this PHP code to the top of your 404 error page. For WordPress, add this your theme's 404.php file:

```
<?php 
/* GoDaddy 404 Redirects FIX - by Daniel Chase - https://riseofweb.com */
$currURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$CheckRedirectError1 = substr($currURL, -6);
$CheckRedirectError2 = substr($currURL, 0, 7);
$CheckRedirectError = false;
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]{5}\/$/",$CheckRedirectError1)){
    $CheckRedirectError = $CheckRedirectError1;
}else if (preg_match("/^\/[a-zA-Z]{5}\/$/",$CheckRedirectError2)){
    $CheckRedirectError = substr($CheckRedirectError2, 1);
}
if($CheckRedirectError){
    $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
    $redirectTo = str_replace($CheckRedirectError, '', $currURL);
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: " . $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $redirectTo);
    exit();
}
?>
```

The script checks for the random characters and removes them, and then redirects to the proper page. You may need to add some exceptions or modify the script to fit your needs.

Comment: I fail to see how a PHP solution could resolve this? The GoDaddy redirect already gets to the correct destination eventually (without the spurious suffix) - which is what your code is trying to do. The "problem" is the variable middle-man redirect (still on the _source_ domain) - which executes _before_ your PHP code gets a chance to do anything!? (_Aside:_ If you already have web hosting associated with the source domain, or can add this as an Addon domain to your current hosting, then there is no need to use GoDaddy's "domain forwarding" interface.)

Comment: @MrWhite in my testing the Godaddy redirects always add the suffix for bots and occasionally add it for real users.   (Like 1 out of 20 times.)   This code could help some.   It seems more cumbersome than implementing the redirects yourself or finding a reliable redirect service though.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Ah, there seems to be two separate (but related) issues here. **#1** The scenario described in the question is a "normal" GoDaddy redirect. The 5-char suffix is only applied to an intermediary redirect. The suffix does not end up on the destination URL. The above PHP code will not do anything. **#2** There appears to have been a "bug" (introduced last year cc. June 2017?) according to the threads you linked to above. The 5-char suffix is erroneously being passed through to the destination URL (not always at the end) and breaking the destination site. The PHP code is for #2.

Comment: Incidentally, the PHP code presented here is remarkably similar to the code at the end of the linked forum thread above: https://uk.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/My-domain-name-not-resolving-correctly-6-random-characters-are/td-p/60782/page/2