# How to redirect / forward a domain to a specific URL?

Tags: domains, dns, 301-redirect, godaddy

So, I tried looking around and haven't found the answer I was looking for. I wanted to ask if it's possible to redirect / forward a domain I bought to a specific URL from another website.

So let's say I have

> `example.com`

and I want to forward it to

> `https://example.net/page/raise_funds_for_charity`

My domain is on Godaddy, so I tried this:

[image]

but it doesn't work, unfortunately.

The domain used to point to a landing page, but when asked to redirect to the specific URL, I deleted the CNAME www entry. I don't know if this caused my problem, I want to know now what's the default value for that.

Comment: I am not sure you can using the GoDaddy option. We do have similar questions, and I do seem to remember one exactly like yours, but I am not finding it now. Sorry. I do not know enough about this option to be of any real help. Cheers!!

Comment: First, you have different protocols in the target URL above (`https`) and in your image (`http`). You'll need to select `https://` in the Domain Control Panel instead of `http://`. Second, the origin URL (`example.com`) would need the same protocol as the target, and if they're both HTTPS, then you'll need an SSL on both ends too. If you don't have that, then I'd recommend using CloudFlare with a flexible SSL, which is free, and you can use Page Rules there to redirect to a specific URL path too. If they're both HTTP however, just make sure your target URL is reachable, and wait...

Comment: since it `can take up to 24-48 hours to activate` as per GoDaddy's help doc here:  [Manually forward or mask your domain or subdomain](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forward-or-mask-your-domain-or-subdomain-422).

Comment: I recently discovered that GoDaddy's redirects don't work for crawlers and occasionally for visitors due to some weird random characters that they server is adding to the URL: [GoDaddy's 301 redirect/forwarding has some weird random middleman URL, kills link juice?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109693/godaddys-301-redirect-forwarding-has-some-weird-random-middleman-url-kills-lin)  Based on that info, I would recommend never redirecting using Godaddy's services.

Comment: Give the true name involved if you want useful help.