# site lost all traffic after installing ssl and moved to a new domain, 301 redirect

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, canonical-url, search-results

About a month ago, I moved my site from http://www.etihadassessment.com to https://www.cabincrewevents.com. My traffic went from 5k pagesviews a day to only 400-600 a day.

I have tested few tools and some are saying that my redirect is perfectly done. And others like screaming frog, say it's a 302! when i'm sure I have redirected the domain as 301 in my godaddy account.

Do I need to add canonical tags at this point? and what can I do to recover the traffic faster?

By the way, I have also changed the internal and external links to all pages and everything loads in SSL protocol.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Godaddy redirects are not reliable.   They have had a severe problem with them for years that has been reported and talked about extensively and yet Godaddy refuses to acknowledge it.   See [GoDaddy's 301 redirect/forwarding has some weird random middleman URL, kills link juice?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109693/godaddys-301-redirect-forwarding-has-some-weird-random-middleman-url-kills-lin)

Comment: "I have tested few tools ..." - what does your browser report?

Answer (score 1):

You only have to test this in a browser to see that there is something "wrong/bizarre" with the redirect. For example:

- Request `http://one.example.com/foo`
- 302 redirect to `http://one.example.com/MPbiZ/foo` (where `MPbiZ` is a random 5 char code that varies every time)
- 302 redirect back to `http://one.example.com/foo`
- 301 redirect to `https://two.example.com/foo`

There is certainly [some weird random middleman URL](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109693/godaddys-301-redirect-forwarding-has-some-weird-random-middleman-url-kills-lin) that @Stephen referenced in comments.

*Aside:* You also have a redirect loop elsewhere in your code (when the page loads) that results in a repeated request for `/2016/04/cabin-crew-cover-letter-examples.html`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That made sense and I have aborted the redirect because of such issues. I appreciate your feedback.