# When I search for a 301 redirected domain Google shows a message from GoDaddy rather than following the 301 redirect

Tags: google, domains, redirects, search-engine-indexing, godaddy

I have a domain name registered at Godaddy. I also have a website that I created at Google Sites. I forward the URL to go to the Google Site. I did this using the Godaddy Domain Manager Forwarding option. The forwarding type is Permanent (301) and it is set to do forwarding only, not forwarding with masking (the latter doesn't work, although I would prefer that if possible).

The forwarding works well—when I type in the URL, it sends me to the Google Sites. The problem is that when I search for the URL in Google, it says:

> Learn how you can get this domain » | See more domains like this ». This Web page is parked FREE, courtesy of GoDaddy. 24/7 Support.

I would like the search to be updated with what information from the Google Sites. How can I do this?

I have tried going to Google Search Console/URL Inspection. It says that the URL is not on Google. I then tried "REQUEST INDEXING." It says that the indexing request is rejected and that "During live testing, indexing issues were detected with the URL". The Page Fetch portion says "Failed: Redirect error."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Godaddy redirects have been broken for years.  Don't use them.  See: [GoDaddy's 301 redirect/forwarding has some weird random middleman URL, kills link juice?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109693/godaddys-301-redirect-forwarding-has-some-weird-random-middleman-url-kills-lin)

In any case, you don't want forwarding at all.   You don't want redirecting and you don't want masking.  You want your domain name to be in the URL for your site.   Follow the instructions here to set your domain name as your custom domain on your Google Site: [Use a custom URL for your site - Sites Help](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/9068867?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

When domains are setup for forwarding, they have the option to Mask their domain to cover up the destination URL. Many companies prevent masking as it is their way of ensuring they are given credit for the website they have created. The blank white page you were expereincing is a result of the destination site's masking prevention measures. Turning off the masking would result in the forwarding working properly.

In regards to the extra characters that are being added to domains that are forwarding, those are related to a security protocol caused by networks detecting high-volume activity or DDOS-like activity in the path between a computer and the website it's trying to access. When customers see those extra letters, it means that whatever was requesting the site, wasn't able to properly respond to the forwarding server in order to get their traffic to be cleared.