# HubSpot CMS site is not secure unless someone types in "www."

Tags: domains, https, security-certificate, cms, godaddy

so we connected our domain with HubSpot CMS. They only support SSL for subdomains, so when someone does not type in "www." they are prompted with a security warning. They told me I needed to set up a redirect through GoDaddy for it to always go to the root domain (`https://example.com`)?

In GoDaddy's forwarding section I see one that says "Domain" and the other says "Subdomain".

What do I type in each of these boxes so that my site goes to `https://example.com` no matter what someone types in?

Comment: Godaddy's redirection services are [horribly broken](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/119025/when-i-search-for-a-301-redirected-domain-google-shows-a-message-from-godaddy-ra/119026#119026) and don't support HTTPS.  I'm not sure why they are suggesting Godaddy as a solution to your problem, because there is no way it will help.

Comment: When you say "HubSpot CMS" do you mean "CMS Hub™" with pricing that [starts at nearly $3000 per year](https://www.hubspot.com/pricing/cms?term=annual)?  If so, that seems really expensive to not do HTTPS redirects for your bare domain and have such poor customer support.

Comment: You might be able to use CloudFlare if you are also willing to use them as a CDN for your site.  CloudFlare does do HTTP to HTTPS redirects and handles the certificates for you.   I know hot to [set up their services for alternate domains](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113180/how-to-avoid-ssl-warnings-about-certificate-not-for-the-current-site-when-redire/129449#129449) for free.   However, I think that using CloudFlare for your bare domain would also necessitate using them as a CDN for your www subdomain.