# Forwarding GoDaddy domain and all its URLs to a new domain

Tags: redirects, domain-forwarding

I have two domains on GoDaddy (`a.example`, `b.example`). I went to the `a.com` DNS administration and forwarded it to `b.example` using a 301 type.

If I go to `a.example`, it correctly redirects me to `b.example`. But, if I go to `a.example/something`, the redirection doesn't work and just gives me a 404 error on a white page, leaving me in the same URL.
What I would expect is that `a.example/something` would redirect to `b.example/something` or at least to `b.example`.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by "on GoDaddy?"  Is GoDaddy your registrar your DNS, or your web host, or all three?  If you have hosting there, which hosting plan are you on?

Comment: BTW, I don't recommend using GoDaddy's forwarding services that are available through their DNS administration.  They have problems that for me are a non-starter.  See: [GoDaddy's 301 redirect/forwarding has some weird random middleman URL, kills link juice?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109693/godaddys-301-redirect-forwarding-has-some-weird-random-middleman-url-kills-lin)

Comment: Does your DNS administration have an option for "Wild Card Redirect"? This is from my cPanel: "Checking the Wild Card Redirect Box will redirect all files within a directory to the same filename in the redirected directory."

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a 301 redirect using .htaccess file.

In your GoDaddy hosting panel, go to the file manager screen for your `a.com` domain, and add an .htaccess file. Then add this code and change `www.yournewdomain.com` to the actual domain of `b.com`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yournewdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That should then do the redirects as you described.