# Forwarding a GoDaddy domain, but HTTPS requests are not forwarding

Tags: dns, https, godaddy, http, domain-forwarding

I'm working through my first attempt at domain forwarding, and it should be simple, but I'm running into difficulty with HTTPS requests. Part of this is I'm working with a friend who has an old web developer, and I'm trying to figure out how to communicate this.

My domain `oldsite.example` is with GoDaddy. I also have domain `newsite.example` with GoDaddy. The initial domain forwarding was simple. I set up `oldsite.example` to forward to a specific URL at `newsite.example` (`https://newsite.example`). Result: if I type either `oldsite.example` or `http://oldsite.example` into the address bar, I get to `newsite.example`. Great. BUT, if I type in `https://oldsite.example`, I get a page that loads forever, then eventually says the server is not responding.

I understand this issue is that, wherever the oldsite is hosted (this is where I'm unclear from the previous developer), there needs to be some action taken to forward HTTPS requests to HTTP -- right? Because the oldsite is not hosted with GoDaddy, and I don't see any active SSL certificates through GoDaddy. I tried to communicate this to the old developer (via my friend), and he seems to think I just forwarded the domain incorrectly in GoDaddy. But I talked to GoDaddy support for an entire HOUR, and they said the site is not hosted with them, so they can't help with forwarding HTTPS requests.

Comment: So when you are saying that you forwarded the domain you probably use the settings in godaddy's DNS settings? If so they are now the host of your older wall and they're only purpose for hosting is to do the redirect.

Comment: Thanks so much. Correct, I followed the instructions here https://www.godaddy.com/help/forward-my-godaddy-domain-12123. I was first under the impression GoDaddy would be the new host but was told adamantly by GoDaddy support that I had to buy a plan to host with them. They even looked up my site and showed me it wasn't hosted with GD. But the old web developer is insisting he can't do anything. I'm feeling a bit stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Godaddy's forwarding services have problems and shouldn't be used:

- [GoDaddy's 301 redirect/forwarding has some weird random middleman URL, kills link juice?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109693/godaddys-301-redirect-forwarding-has-some-weird-random-middleman-url-kills-lin)
- They don't support HTTPS

One way to solve the problem would be to buy hosting from Godaddy and redirect from the hosting.  That would support HTTPS and give you more control.  It would also be expensive.

The better alternative is to use CloudFlare to redirect your old domain. You can do so with their free service tier, so it doesn't cost anything. I've found their redirects to be reliable. They automatically handle the certificates and configuration for HTTPS for you. It takes a bit of work to set up: you have to change our NS records at GoDaddy to point to the name servers that CloudFlare gives you and then do some configuration in your CloudFlare account.  Complete instructions are here: [How to avoid SSL warnings about certificate not for the current site when redirecting alternate domains?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113180/how-to-avoid-ssl-warnings-about-certificate-not-for-the-current-site-when-redire)

Answer (score 0):

I just did mine with redirect.pizza (not affiliated with them).  I have my domain hosted a godaddy.  Now both http and https://oldsite.example as well as [www.oldsite.example](http://www.oldsite.example) forward to https://newsite.example .  I wasn't able to do this with godaddy's domain forwarding.